# Create consecutive ID based on non-consecutive ID in Stata

Tags: stata

Given the following variables (`id` and `partner`) in Stata, I would like to create a new variable (`pid`) that is simply the consecutive partner counter within `id` (as you can see, `partner` is not consecutive). Here is a MWE:

```
clear
input   id  partner pid
        1   1       1
        1   1       1
        1   3       2
        1   3       2
        2   2       1
        2   3       2
        2   3       2
        2   3       2
        2   5       3
        2   5       3
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// create example data
clear
input   id  partner
        1   1      
        1   1      
        1   3      
        1   3     
        2   2     
        2   3     
        2   3     
        2   3     
        2   5     
        2   5     
end

// create pid
bysort id partner : gen pid = _n == 1
by id : replace pid = sum(pid)

// admire the result
list, sepby(id)
```

Comment: Another way to do it: `bysort id (partner) : gen pid = sum(partner != partner[_n-1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Maarten! I will wait for a few minutes and then accept your answer.